# Meteor Handlebars: What is the proper way in a condition to compare two variables?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I can't figure out a way to do something like this in a Template with Meteor and Handlebars:

```
{{#if var1 == var2}}
{{/if}}
```

I've also set up the [Meteor Handlebars Helpers](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers) and this seems not to work too [while it should](https://github.com/raix/Meteor-handlebar-helpers/issues/9):

```
{{#if $eq var1 var2}}
{{/if}}
```

So what is your proper way to compare two variables with Handlebars in a Template?

EDIT: In fact, this seems to go beyond the Handlebar ideology which is that [there should be no logic in templates](http://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/18a5in/about_handlebarsjss_ideology_is_it_me_or_is_it_bad/).

Comment: Handlebars is getting deprecated and you won't be able to upgrade to newer versions of Meteor if you use Handlebars helpers. Please refer to 0.8 rc announcements and docs.

Comment: Thank you for this information. By the way, what does mean rc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now this is not as easy as you might aspect. I thought i have read that this is maybe a feature in meteor 1.0.

You have the 3 following possibilities:

html:

```
<template name="stuff">
  {{#if isTrue}}
    ...
  {{else}}
    ...
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

js:

```
Template.stuff.helpers({
  isTrue: function () {
    return var1 === var2;
  }
});
```

Another possibility is to provide an own handlebars helper:

html:

```
{{compare "var1" "var2"}}
```

js:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('compare', function(var1, var2) {
  return var1 === var2;
});
```

Or you use any other Handlebars-helper package where someone already did the work for you. I dont know the package you used, so i cant give a detailed solution about your problem but maybe you get a nice view of how this can be realised.